# How do i get these divs to stack properly when there is absolute positioning inside one?

Tags: html, css

Man...tough crowd here...this is a little discouraging.  I rarely post questions here but when I do, it's honestly because I have spent hours searching for a solution and for whatever reason, can't find one.  I thought the purpose of this community was to help others, instead of just trying to show your superiority.  I have read far too many threads where most of the commenting and answers are not even relevant to the original question, and I'm just wondering why so much time is spent on bashing others instead of trying to help?  I came to you because I am not very familiar with html and css, and every time I tried something I found it only tended to mess things up.  This is why I left most of the code intact, because when I changed something too much in the section, it changed more variables than I intended, which I thought may have an impact on the usability of a solution suggested, so I left most of the code alone.  Obviously there are problems, and yes someone with real skill in this area should be doing the edits, but isn't that why I am here?  Because I am trying to do what I can with the resources I have and am seeking some help from experts?  I just don't understand when this site became more about showing others up than about helping the less fortunate.  It's like, a guy runs out of gas on the freeway because of some irrelevant circumstance, whether it's because his gauge was misreporting or because he didn't understand how to use the pump at the station, or he was just forgetful...whatever, he is asking for help, needs a ride or a phone to borrow to call a friend, and you approach, slow down and yell while driving by, "You know you really should keep your tank 1/2 full!" or "Your paint looks like crap! Get it fixed and then I'll stop!"

---

Please everyone viewing, this is old code, I am tasked with cleaning it up, so I really would appreciate not being beat up on the problems with coding technique...I'm just trying to get the answer to my question to solve this problem to move forward.  And I really did research this, but because of the need to not use fixed height on the image and the fact that I need the outside divs to position relatively...it creates a unique scenario, at least I think.

---

I am confused on how to get these divs to stack properly.  I can't get the main content div (on line 6) to stack below the first div that has/involves absolute positioning (so that the one image is on top of the other).

I also need to keep from using fixed height on the image.  Because I don't want that to lock in where the second div starts.  If the screen is sized down then I want the image to size down proportionally.  Is that possible?

Here is the code I am working with:

https://jsfiddle.net/se5Le7w2/1/

I tried using position: relative on the outer divs but it doesn't seem to do what I'm trying to achieve.

```
  <div style="position: relative;">
    <div style="max-width: 975px; width: 100%;">
      <img style="position: absolute; z-index: 102; max-width: 975px; width: 100%;" src="http://www.pegaweb.com/tutorials/web-page-header/5.gif">
      <img style="position: absolute; z-index: 103; margin-left: 40px; margin-top: 20px;" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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">
    </div>
    <div style="position: relative; width: 100%;">
      <table style="width: 100%; max-width: 975px;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <p style="text-align: justify; font-size: 11px; line-height: 14px; margin: 0px 0px 14px; padding: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; letter-spacing: normal; orphans: auto; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: 1; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px;">
              1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce ultrices justo justo, ac consequat arcu pellentesque id. Nulla hendrerit dui vitae neque venenatis consequat. Morbi justo eros, dictum et enim et, pellentesque fermentum augue. Aliquam
              non sapien eros. Sed auctor enim ac blandit rhoncus. Vivamus condimentum ex nulla, quis laoreet risus sodales quis. Vivamus interdum aliquam ultricies. Donec consectetur turpis et vehicula hendrerit. Fusce ac dui nec odio convallis malesuada
              id ultricies lectus.
            </p>
            <p style="text-align: justify; font-size: 11px; line-height: 14px; margin: 0px 0px 14px; padding: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; letter-spacing: normal; orphans: auto; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: 1; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px;">
              2. Nam mi enim, bibendum id porttitor quis, posuere ac arcu. Donec pulvinar enim nec gravida accumsan. Fusce enim risus, laoreet nec venenatis aliquam, feugiat a sapien. Aenean vulputate fermentum ex, at cursus diam cursus vel. Vivamus maximus velit mi,
              ut auctor libero hendrerit ut. Donec vel pharetra nulla. Aenean imperdiet elementum felis vel finibus. Aenean eu luctus velit, nec accumsan velit.
            </p>
            <p style="text-align: justify; font-size: 11px; line-height: 14px; margin: 0px 0px 14px; padding: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; letter-spacing: normal; orphans: auto; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: 1; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px;">
              3. Nullam pharetra orci nec lacinia bibendum. Ut tortor dolor, feugiat sed nulla ac, ultricies vehicula mi. Donec in arcu tincidunt, convallis lectus eu, ornare eros. Duis mollis ultrices lacus vulputate iaculis. Quisque urna lorem, consectetur in sollicitudin
              ut, volutpat et ex. Integer finibus malesuada ipsum, eget consequat nulla interdum et. Maecenas ullamcorper ante turpis, vitae mattis libero ultricies a. Duis bibendum sapien vitae molestie interdum.
            </p>
            <p style="text-align: justify; font-size: 11px; line-height: 14px; margin: 0px 0px 14px; padding: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; letter-spacing: normal; orphans: auto; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: 1; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px;">
              4. Vestibulum cursus ipsum augue, eget consequat dui ullamcorper sed. Phasellus a ligula eu tellus posuere tristique quis eu odio. Nullam id est in orci pharetra tempus sed dictum sem. Phasellus vehicula iaculis augue ac scelerisque. Sed pretium eros
              sed tortor condimentum viverra. Quisque euismod sed ante eu facilisis. Quisque rhoncus auctor arcu at aliquet. Pellentesque eleifend leo at nisl fringilla sagittis. Sed augue erat, faucibus a nulla at, porttitor volutpat dui.
            </p>
            <p style="text-align: justify; font-size: 11px; line-height: 14px; margin: 0px 0px 14px; padding: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; letter-spacing: normal; orphans: auto; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: 1; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px;">
              5. Maecenas semper erat euismod, ultricies augue et, aliquam ipsum. Sed commodo diam a posuere tristique. Vestibulum placerat risus orci, vitae finibus libero vulputate sed. Vestibulum ac nulla maximus, lobortis turpis interdum, tempor lectus. Fusce pretium
              scelerisque viverra. Vestibulum aliquam at ex eget sollicitudin. Proin in vehicula velit. Nam eget metus sed dui lobortis pulvinar sit amet sed tortor. Aliquam eu nunc a tortor ultricies euismod.
            </p>
          </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>

            <img src="http://www.pegaweb.com/tutorials/web-page-header/5.gif" class="footer" style="width: 100%; max-width: 975px; position: relative; cursor: pointer;">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: That's a lot of nesting...dear lord...

Comment: wow the style in the html ....

Comment: It's a complex page and this is just one section, i am trying to refine things and address these issues so please, let me know if you have any suggestions with regards to my question, because that is one of the first steps I need to accomplish.

Comment: Alon Eitan - So are you saying you can't stack images on top of each other inside a div and still have that div positioned inline relative to others on the page?  I don't understand.  I can't use margin and padding to push it down because the images are meant to size down on small screens and if they do, then the margin/padding will be disproportionate.

Comment: @sds Here is a possible solution - the wrapping div of the 2 images (the one with the `max-width: 975px;` style) - Give it `height: 238px;`

Comment: why you not do already one file for the html and one for your css it will be more easy to work with it and then you do really a lot of nesting with your tables .... you can not do it with something like flexbox? is just an idea

Comment: @AlonEitan - I thought of that but as I said, if you size the page down, and the images size down with it, then you have a whitespace gap.

Answer (score 0):

I'd comment instead of answering but my reputation is not high enough yet.

You have an unnecesary amount of elements nested. The `table` element should not be used to layout your page. Use `div` and only when needed. For what I see in your fiddle, you just need a few divs, maybe only 2.

Also, inline `CSS` is NOT recommended. Use an external file.

I know this is not the answer you're looking for, but the way things are, no one will even try to help you as long as you have such unnecesary complexities.

Comment: I refined it a bit I think so hopefully it's more workable.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot wrong with your HTML and inline CSS but that's beyond the scope of this question.

Basically to easily solve your issue, you need to set a fixed height to one of your nested `<div>` and `<img>` tags.

Here :

```
   <div style="position: relative">
       <div style="max-width: 975px; width: 100%; height: 250px">
       <img style="position: absolute;z-index: 102;max-width: 975px;width: 100%;top: 0;left: 0;height: 150px;" src="http://www.pegaweb.com/tutorials/web-page-header/5.gif">
   </div>
```

Have a look at this article for further information :

[Inline CSS BAD](http://robertnyman.com/2008/11/20/why-inline-css-and-javascript-code-is-such-a-bad-thing/)

Comment: I can't use fixed height for the reasons I added above.